# if the snapshots download allowed by default for repository configure in pom.xml

Tags: maven

I notice there are configures as followed:

```
 <repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>snapshots-repo</id>
     <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
     <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
     <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
   </repository>
 </repositories>
```

so my question is, if not configure ***snapshots*** and ***release*** elements, if allowed the snapshot download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default value](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-settings/settings.html#class_snapshots) for the `snapshots` option is `true`.